# Add the hash of the code in executable file

Tags: stm32, flash-memory

I have an STM32 application which uses two blocks of memory. In 0th block, I have a boot code (which runs just after power-on) and in 7th block, I have an application code (which may or may not run depending on the authorization decision given by the boot code).

Those two codes are developed hence generated by two separate projects. They are flashed on the specific blocks (boot code to 0th block and application code to 7th block) of STM32 NOR memory using *openocd* tool by giving an *offset* value to the openocd's *write_image* command.

What I would like to do basically in the boot code is that I want to calculate the hash of the application code and compare it with the reference digest. If they are equal, I will give the hand to the application code. For that, after I generate the executable (can be in elf, hex or bin format) of the application code, I want to:

- Create another file (in any format listed above) which has 128K byte size
- Copy the content of the executable file to the recently created file from its beginning (0 offset)
- Write the hash of the executable to the last 32 bytes of the recently created file
- Fill the gap with 0xFF
- Finally flash this executable file (if it is still) to the 7th block of the memory

Do you think that it is doable and feasible? If so:

- Which format should I use to generate the executable?
- Do I have something that I need to give specific attention to achieve this?

Lastly, do you think that it makes sense to do that or is there any other more standard way for this purpose?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add an additional step to your building sequence. After the linking extract the binary file from elf
Then write a program in your favourite programming language which will calculate something and append the result to that bin file